# Error en OracleXE21

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, express

soy nuevo en Oracle Database 21c Express Edition, estoy intentando conectarme a la base de datos pugable y me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me puede orientar cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Pues a) algo en el tnsnames.ora del cliente no está bien definido y ese servidor no está identificado allí, o b) ese servidor cshayblablabla.oradev.oraclecorp.com no puede resolverse. Mas alla de eso, no sabemos dónde está desplegada esa BD o cómo está configurado el tnsnames.ora del cliente

Comment: Gracias, por tu observación. Pues estoy instalando la versión Oracle Express, es ahí donde tengo la duda, porque dentro de los archivos no me aparece un documento listener.ora o el tnsnames.ora. Te comparto una captura, talvez, con tu experiencia logre hacerlo. Intente ingresar por consola con el comando "connect" remplace "CSHAY..." por "localhost" y no me dejo.

Comment: Esa captura es del instalador. EL archivo estará en la instalación, que debe estar en C:/ProgramFIles/oracle/ o alguna cosa así. Es como si tuvieras problemas con Windows y buscaras en el CD de instalación. Revisa la documentación sobre cómo configurar el tnsnames.ora del instantClient, que es lo que estás usando

Comment: Vale, estoy instalando nuevamente, voy a revisar nuevamente el tuto y la documentación como me sugieres. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, ya cree el documento tnsnames de la siguiente manera: ORA21C=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ora21c)
  )
)
 Deseo hacer una conexión local, adicionalmente me solicita crear un documento sqlnet.ora, pero no me sale info. mire este tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ll7_VcwePN4